# Off the Derech Parent

Tags: shabbat, kashrut-kosher, tznius-modesty, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, chagim-holidays

In what instances to kibbud av v'em apply to a parent who has become less religious?

For example, of the following points, which battles are worth fighting?

- Kashrut
- Shabbat
- Chaggim
- tzniut

As always, CYLOR.

Comment: Is the child still living in the parent's home?

Comment: I am having trouble with the question.  Are you asking about if kibbud av applies or which is the most important thing to "fight" over in the event you can't fight everything?  What does kibbud av have to do with keeping kosher or Shabbos?

Comment: @Yishai, yes this is assuming that the child still lives at the parent's home.

Comment: @YEZ, My question is assuming, that as I mentioned to Yishai, the child still lives at home, what points are worth- or should be fought over, whether they bring treif into the house or watch television on shabbat or wear revealing clothing, whether they use a theoretically kosher grill for neveilot or cooking on shabbat.

Comment: Why is the child fighting over anything? The child needs to keep Halakha. I don't know what Kibbud Av vaEm have to do with anything.

Comment: This really can only be answered by a Rabbi who knows the child and parents,every circumstance is diff,a parent could never go against halacha ,however living with non religious family members one needs the help from a Rabbi who understands the situation and most importantly alot of Sayata DiShmaya

Comment: I was asking what @DoubleAA just repeated.  What does this have to do with kibbud av?

Comment: @DoubleAA, the rationale for tagging with kibbud av v'em is that the child is trying to keep halachah, while their parent(s) have gone off the derech. Thus the conflict between the child and parent(s) makes it an issue of kibbud av v'em

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt i don't follow the logic of your comment? What conflict? What does that have to do with KAA?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm not sure how else to phrase my logic, however the way I view it, there is a question of kibbud av v'em here.

Comment: What do you think the obligation of KAA is? (In general, logic always becomes clearer the more you make your deductions explicit. Try listing assumptions you take at each step.)

Comment: _Kibud av vaem_ is catering to a parent: if my father asks me to fry him an egg (at his expense), I must obey. Is your question about what I should do if he asks me to fry him an egg with cheese and ground meat? That's a reasonable question IMO (and one to which I happen to know the answer), but I'm unsure whether it's what you mean to ask.

Comment: Isn't the title of the question "Off the derech" parent somewhat derogatory and a lack of Kibud of Va'em? I know what the words mean, literally, but it seems to say, "Mom or dad, you were on the right path, but now you're off of it, and God and I are displeased because of what you're doing." Why not just use the term "unobservant" or "not religious"? "Off the derech" sounds similar to saying about someone "He's a little 'off'" meaning "He's kind of crazy", when the person isn't.

Comment: @DanF "Off the derech" implies that they were once religious, whereas "unobservant" or "not religious" do not have the same connotation, if there is a better phrasing, I am open to it.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I guess I'm not up to current terminology. My grandparents were "partially" Shomer Shabbat. They went to shul. Grandma lit Shabbat candles, had Shabbat meals but watched TV and used the phone. I never heard of the term "derech" used in a phrase other than "take food for the derech". I referred to their practice as "not completely Shomer Shabbat". I know that's a complex phrase to describe your situation. I guess I'm an "old fashioned young guy who's not up to current yeshivish terminology" ;-)

Comment: @DanF, to be honest, I first came across the term from either Wiki or some Yeshivish bochrim.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - I have the book "Yeshivish" (forgot the author's name). I don't think this phrase is in there. That book has to be updated (and so do I.) Personally, I don't like the phrase. To me, it implies that there is only one "path" and the person is not on it. It appears to fail to acknowledge those that are doing SOMETHING right so they are really ON the "derech" but decided to take a "pit stop" for a while :-)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=tPQOX87XxaUC&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false) (#4) regarding the halachos of correcting a parent.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Primary sources for the above include: *Kidushin* ([32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=32&format=text)), Rambam ([*Hil. Mamrim* 6:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=81&perek=6&halocha=11)), *Shulchan Aruch* ([YD 240:11](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6694)), and *Aruch HaShulchan* ([YD 240:33](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%9E#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.9E_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9C.D7.92)).

Answer (score 2):

There's a general rule that if a parent asks or makes you violate any halacha, you should not listen to them. As you know, within halacha there are interpretations, minimal requirements and leniencies. You need to have a clear understanding of how these work for each action and situation. So, while I have mentioned a general guideline, there si no tacit answer for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

You are obligated to treat them with an attitude of respect, and speak to them respectfully. However, you should still keep shabbos, kosher, and the like, despite their wishes to the contrary. (When it comes to something like a custom or chumra, it can vary.) That means saying "I love you mom, but sorry, I feel that I need to eat kosher", not "mom you apikorus, you're going to gehenom for eating that treif!"